# How to send res.json() in Express JS from a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rethinkdb

I am trying to send a json response when an API call is triggered from front-end, I'm not able to send the `res.json()` when I am getting the data from a for loop. Where I am writing a query to search in multiple Tables. I am using RethinkDB.

I want `res.json()` to send data after the query, But I don't understand what mistake I am doing. :(

Thanks in advence

## zeasts

Here is the following code and [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/1bwxLjqs/1/) too.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const moment = require('moment');
const r = require('rethinkdb');
const tableNameDB = ['assets', 'alerts',  'destinations']


router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
        let resData = []
        let searchValue = req.body.searchValue,
            tableName = req.body.tableName;
        newCallForSearch(res, searchValue, resData)
    })

function newCallForSearch (res, searchValue, resData){
    let anArray = ['captain']
    for(var i = 0; i<tableNameDB.length; i++){
        let tabName = tableNameDB[i]
        r.table(tableNameDB[i]).filter(function(doc) {
            return doc.coerceTo('string').match(searchValue);
        }).run(rethink_conn, (err, cur) => {
           // console.log(cur)
            if (err) {
                return 0
            } else {
                cur.toArray((err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return 0
                    } else if (result) {
                        let Results = []
                        Results = Object.values(result).slice(0,10)
                        var newResults = Results.map(function() {
                            resData = Object.assign({'tableName': tabName},{'data' : result});
                            anArray.push(resData)
                        })
                    }
                })    
                
            }
                
        })
    }   
    res.status(200);
    res.json(anArray); 
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: FYI, `if (err) return 0` is a giant, giant warning sign of code smell.  You are silently eating errors with zero logging and no thought for real error handling.  I would hate to have to debug a problem in this code as errors are silently thrown away.

Comment: okay, I'll update the return `err` in code... :) Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: `return err` from an asynchronous callback doesn't do anything useful either.  You need to either convert to using promises so it's easier to propagate errors back from nested operations or you need to add a callback to `newCallForSearch()` and communicate back errors that way or you need to actually send an error response in each place an error is detected.  Remember, a response needs to be sent for every request, even if there's an error.  And, you should `console.log(err)` for every error you detect too.

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDb is a functional database and so using it in a functional way will yield the least resistance. We can accomplish more by writing less code.

You can use `Promise.all` to run many subqueries and pass the result to `res.send` -

```js
const search = (table = "", query = "", limit = 10) =>
  r.table(table)
  .filter(doc => doc.coerceTo("string").match(query))
  .toArray()
  .slice(0, limit)
  .do(data => ({ table, data }))

const tables =
  ['assets', 'alerts',  'destinations']

const subqueries =
  tables.map(t => search(t, "foo").run(rethink_conn)) // <-- search each table

Promise.all(subqueries) // <-- run all subqueries
  .then(result => {     // <-- handle success
    res.status(200)
    res.json(result)
  })
  .catch(e => {         // <-- handle failure
    res.status(500)
    res.send(e.message)
  })
```

Or use `.union` to produce a single query -

```js
const search = (table = "", query = "", limit = 10) =>
  r.table(table)
  .filter(doc => doc.coerceTo("string").match(query))
  .toArray()
  .slice(0, limit)
  .do(data => ({ table, data }))

const searchAll = (tables = [], query = "", limit = 10) =>
  tables.reduce
    ( (r, t) => r.union(search(t, query, limit)) // <-- union
    , r.expr([]) // <-- if no tables are supplied, return empty result
    )

const tables =
  ['assets', 'alerts',  'destinations']

searchAll(tables, "foo") // <-- single rethink expr
  .run(rethink_conn)     // <-- run returns a promise
  .then(result => {      // <-- handle success
    res.status(200)
    res.json(result)
  })
  .catch(e => {          // <-- handle failure
    res.status(500)
    res.send(e.message)
  })
```

---

I should remark on the proposed use of `filter` in your original post -

```js
.filter(doc => doc.coerceTo("string").match(query))
```

This is quick but it is also sloppy. It matches `query` against any of `doc`s values, but also the `doc`'s keys. And if `doc` is a complex nested document, it matches them too. User beware.

Comment: What is `table` in `search` const? Similarly query also ?? Where should I pass the string ? And please ignore the `tableName = req.body.tableName;` from my question. I'm not using it anywhere.